# Push not working inside firebase listener

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
var db=firebase.firestore();
var musicidarray=[];
var musicpaircontentarray=[];

//Retreive all music value pairs
db.collection("MusicIdNamePairs").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        musicidarray.push(doc.id);
        musicpaircontentarray.push(doc);
        //alert(doc.get("Name"));
        //console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}`);
    });
});
alert(musicidarray.length);//Suprisingly outputs length as zero even when the previou loop has run
for(var i=0;i<musicpaircontentarray.length;i++)
{
    alert(musicpaircontentarray[i].get("Name"));
}
```

Here the `musicidarray` and the `musicpaircontentarray` (storing the document reference obtained from Cloud Firestore) is showing length as zero even after it has executed the push operation inside the foreach loop in the previous block of code.What is wrong here.Please help me.Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
        var db=firebase.firestore();
        var musicidarray=[];
        var musicpaircontentarray=[];

        //Retreive all music value pairs
        db.collection("MusicIdNamePairs").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                musicidarray.push(doc.id);
                musicpaircontentarray.push(doc);
                //alert(doc.get("Name"));
                //console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}`);
            });
            displayarray();
        });
        function displayarray()
        {
            alert(musicidarray.length);
            for(var i=0;i<musicpaircontentarray.length;i++)
            {
                alert(musicpaircontentarray[i].get("Name"));
            }
        }
    </script>
```

The issue here as far as my understanding is that the array.length is called even before the data is retrieved from the database(even though the content is after the loop in the script and looks as if the length is called after only the loop is executed).Instead, call the display array method after the entire loop is assured to be completed as in the solution.

Hope this is the right way. If I am wrong somewhere, please correct me.

Comment: This is indeed the correct approach. Upvoted! :-)   If you search for [questions about Cloud Firestore for JavaScript about asynchronous behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D%5Bjavascript%5D+asynchronous) you'll find a lot more questions describing this behavior.

Comment: Thank you for the upvote and for sharing more information about this